# probability - vehicle arriving and gap in between them

Tags: probability, poisson-distribution

Vehicle arriving at an intersection from one of the approach roads follow the Poisson distribution. The mean rate of arrival is 900 vehicles per hour. If a gap is defined as the time difference between two successive vehicle arrivals (with vehicle  assumed to be points), the probability that the gap is greater than 8 seconds is ____.

My approach for solving above question:

If 900 vehicles are passing per hour -> $\frac{1}{4}$ vehicles passing per second. So in 4 seconds 1 vehicle passes and in 8 seconds 2 vehicles can pass.

The problem I am facing here is how that gap is related with the question.
It says gap is greater than 8 seconds -> now in 8 seconds 1 vehicle come but earlier in 8 seconds 2 vehicles used to come. so at this point I can say mean of event is 2. i.e. value of lambda is 2. so now are we finding P(X>1) => 1 - P(X=0) i.e. finding probability of more than 1 car will pass in 8 seconds having mean of 2. This last point I am not understanding properly.

Comment: maybe the following question and answer can help you: [](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1074984/using-poisson-distribution-to-find-the-probability-that-the-interval-between-arr?rq=1)

Answer (score 1):

As you said, the mean rate of arrival is $\lambda = \frac{1}{4} \frac{\text{vehicles}}{s}$. By the problem statement, the probability of $n$ cars passing in a time interval $t$ is 
$$ P_n(t) = \frac{(\lambda t)^n}{n!}e^{-\lambda t}.$$
If $F_n(t)$ is the probability that $n$ cars have passed at time $t$, the probability that $n$ cars have also passed at time $t + \delta t$ is 
$$ F_n(t+\delta t) = Pr(\text{n cars have passed in t})Pr(\text{no cars have passed between } t \text{ and } t+ \delta t)$$
$$ F_n(t+\delta t) = F_n(t) (1-\lambda \delta t).$$ 
Taking $\delta t  \rightarrow 0$ and using the definition of the derivative gives the differential equation 
$$ \frac{d}{dt}F_n(t) = -\lambda F_n(t)$$
for the probability that only $n$ cars have passed at time $t$. This has the solution (it's separable)
$$ F_n(t) = \lambda e^{-\lambda t}.$$
Therefore, the distribution of times between cars passing is an exponential distribution with mean $\lambda$. 
The probability that the gap is greater than $8$ seconds is 
$$Pr(t>8) = \int_{8}^{\infty}\frac{1}{4} e^{-\frac{1}{4}t},$$
which you can easily evaluate.